# How can I communicate with an already running Linux process in Python?

Tags: python, linux, server, client, ipc

I am simulating an **https** session between a client and server within the same **Ubuntu Linux** virtual machine. Naturally, the client process (*client.py*) sends requests to the server process (*server.py*) which will already be running before the client spawns to make its request. For security reasons, I would prefer avoid spawning an intermediate shell to pass commands to the server via something like the *system()* function call [*os.system* **module**]; The server is an independent process that is already running so it does not make sense to use the subproccess **module** in Python because the server will not be a child process. Do I have to use sockets? If so, what python module supports sockets? Is there some other form of interprocess communication on Linux? What to do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/languages/python/).
It is simple to use and it provides a single abstraction to various communication modes, including sockets.